# Copy past embedded resource file

Tags: vb.net, copy-paste, embedded-resource

I am trying to refrence a file and copy and past it at runtime, however I cant get it to work...

```
        Dim rm As Resources.ResourceManager
    rm = New Resources.ResourceManager("Rectangular_Profiles.Resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly)
    Dim Instance As IO.FileInfo = rm.GetObject("REC-SQU-NON.ipt")
    Instance.CopyTo("C:\REC-SQU-NOn.ipt")
```

Comment: Normally, there is a permissions problem if you try to have the program copy to your root (C:\).  Have you tried copying the file to a folder in "My Documents"?

Comment: yeah just tried that too but no file found and no errors either? it just dose nothing

Comment: You might also try casting the object as IO.FileInfo: Dim Instance As IO.FileInfo = DirectCast(rm.GetObject("REC-SQU-NON.ipt"), IO.FileInfo)

Comment: @Dustin this dosnt work either.... what i might add though is that this code is added to th begining of my form-load event which worker fine untill now. fair enougth this code dosnt work but the next step in my form load event dosnt seem to do anything either. kake away my new addition the form load event rolls again ... so there is definatly sothing with these few ;lines of code

Comment: have you tried putting the code in a try-catch block to catch an error?

Comment: Okay made a try-catch now it says that its not set to an instance of an object wich I dont get because i always refrence my images from the recources so I know that the file/ objcet is there ... though this time I made use of files instead of images in my rescouces  and I tried the file name with and without extention... the destination folder also exists :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112144/discussion-between-tm80-and-dustin).